# Obtain step sizes of (stiff) ODE solver with fixed time span vector, but variable integration step size

Tags: matlab, ode

I am trying to solve a stiff ODE using [`ode15s`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15s.html). The solver takes a very small step size at some points during the simulation, which I would like to inspect more in-depth.

Depending on the model parameters, the system can have >1000 states, and therefore I am using a time span with fixed step size (Otherwise the states are saved for every tiny step size, which I don't really need, and takes too much RAM). The ODE solver still uses a variable step size (as it should).

However, I would like to obtain the 'actual' time vector used by the ODE solver, to analyse why the solver takes such small steps for some states/transisiton. How can I obtain this time vector, in addition to the fixed step size time vector `t` and state matrix `y`?

An MCVE:

```
tspan = [0 2000];
tstep = 10;

tspan_fix = tspan(1):tstep:tspan(2);
[t_fix,y_fix] = ode15s(@vdp1000, tspan_fix, [2 0]);

tspan_var = tspan;
[t_var,y_var] = ode15s(@vdp1000, tspan_var, [2 0]);

figure(1); clf;
subplot(211)
plot(t_fix,y_fix(:,1),'-o')
subplot(212)
plot(t_var,y_var(:,1),'-o')
```

[image]

So as you can see, `ode15s` will in both cases use variable step size, but the points at which the solution is evaluated is different. This I want to keep with fixed step size, but it'd be interesting to see where the solver is taking these small steps.

---

Something more like real life (using outputFcn etc.):

```
% set ode plot/log settings
odeOpts = odeset();
if usejava('desktop') 
    % use figure progressbar if interactive session
    odeOpts = odeset(odeOpts, 'OutputFcn',@odeprog,'Events',@odeabort);
    % odeOpts = odeset(odeOpts, 'OutputFcn',@outputFcnWrapper); % to use multiple outputfcn / eventfcn
else
    % otherwise print progress every 1 ms of simulation
    odeOpts = odeset(odeOpts, 'OutputFcn', @(t,y,flag)odeprogress_mini(t,y,flag,PM.Tend)); 
end

% set ode integration settings
odeOpts = odeset(odeOpts, 'stats', 'on');

% numerical integration
tstep = 0.01;   % ms
Tend = 40;      % ms
tspan = 0:tstep:Tend;
[t, y] = ode15s(@(t, y) myode(t, y), tspan, y0);
```

Comment: how `myode(t, y)` looks like?

Comment: The complete ODE is a bit too big, I will change this to an example ODE.

Comment: @Adam added an MCVE.